# Unable to present a UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have the following view hierarchy:

```
                         UINavigationController
                                  ||
                                  \/
           LibraryTableViewController: UITableViewController
                                  ||
                                  \/
       AlbumsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController
                                  ||
                                  \/
             SongsTableViewController: UITableViewController
```

I want to have a search bar in `AlbumsCollectionViewController` and a different one in `SongsTableViewController` that is shown in the `navigationItem.titleView`.

I have managed to add a working search bar in `AlbumsCollectionViewController` as follows:

```
class AlbumsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initSearchBar()
        initNavigationBar()
    }

    private func initSearchBar() {
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = true
    }

    private func initNavigationBar() {
        searchButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        settingsButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        backButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.title = "Artists"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    }


    @IBAction func SearchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        showSearchBar()
    }


    private func showSearchBar(){
        navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = false
        searchController.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Note that the search bar is hidden on `ViewDidLoad()` and is presented when a button is pressed as shown in `SearchButtonTapped` method.

Now, I am trying to do the same in `SongsTableViewController` however, the search bar is not showing when tapping the the button (i.e. calling `SearchButtonTapped`) and I am getting the following message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UISearchController: 0x7f8158812b50> on <MyProject.AlbumsCollectionViewController: 0x7f81588023c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

If I commented the line `searchController.isActive = true` then the search bar will show, however, it wont be active even if I tapped on it.

**Edit**

Sorry if I haven't been clear. I have a separate `UISearchController` in `SongsTableViewController`. I meant I am using the same logic in both controllers

**Also Note if I pushed `SongsTableViewController` from the navigation controller (i.e the view hierarchy only has 2 controllers (UINavigationController => SongsTableViewController) the search bar works fine**

**This is most of the Code of  `SongsTableViewController` (omitted non relevant stuff)**

```
import UIKit
import os.log
import MediaPlayer

class SongsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate ,PlayerDelegate, NowPlayingDelegate, SongCellDelegate, SongsOptionsDelegate {

    // MARK: properties

    var playerManager: PlayerManager? = nil
    var dataManager: DataManager? = nil

    var tabVC: TabBarController?
    var selectedSong: Song?

    lazy var optionsTransitionDelegate = PresentationManager()
    lazy var playlistTransitionDelegate = PresentationManager()

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var albumID: String?
    var artistID: String?
    var playlist: Playlist?

    var songs = [Song]()
    var songIndexMap = [String: Int]()
    var filteredSongs = [Song]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataManager = DataManager.getInstance()
        self.playerManager = PlayerManager.getInstance()

        playlistTransitionDelegate.screenRatio = 2.0 / 3.0

        if(self.albumID != nil) {
            self.songs = SQLiteManager.getAlbumSongs(albumID: self.albumID!)
        } else if(self.artistID != nil) {
            self.songs = SQLiteManager.getArtistSongs(artistID: self.artistID!)
        } else if (self.playlist != nil) {
            self.songs = SQLiteManager.getPlaylistSongs(playlist: self.playlist!)
        } else {
            dataManager?.songsTableViewController = self
        }

        for i in 0..<songs.count {
            songIndexMap[songs[i].id] = i
        }

        initSearchBar()
        initNavigationBar()

        if(songs.count == 0 && (!fullListOfSongs() || fullListOfSongs() && dataManager?.getFullSongsCount() == 0)){
            tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
        }
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        tabVC = tabBarController as? TabBarController
        tabVC?.nowPlayingViewController?.delegate = self


    }



    private func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return Util.SONG_CELL_HEIGHT
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(isFiltering()) {
            return self.filteredSongs.count
        } else if (fullListOfSongs()) {
            return dataManager!.getFullSongsCount()
        }
        return self.songs.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "SongTableViewCell"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? SongCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of SongCell.")
        }
        var song: Song?
        if(fullListOfSongs()) {
            if(isFiltering()){
                song = self.filteredSongs[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                song = dataManager?.getSong(index: indexPath.row)
            }
        } else {
            if(isFiltering()){
                song = self.filteredSongs[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                song = self.songs[indexPath.row]
            }
        }

        cell.setAttributes(song: song!)
        cell.delegate = self

        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }



    // MARK: - Search Bar

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if (!searchController.isActive) {
            hideSearchBar()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        if(isSearchBarEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        filterSongs(filter: searchController.searchBar.text!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    private func filterSongs(filter: String) {
        if(self.albumID != nil) {
            self.filteredSongs = SQLiteManager.getAlbumSongs(albumID: self.albumID!, filter: filter)
        } else if(self.artistID != nil) {
            self.filteredSongs = SQLiteManager.getArtistSongs(artistID: self.artistID!, filter: filter)
        } else if(self.playlist != nil) {
            self.filteredSongs = SQLiteManager.getPlaylistSongs(playlist: self.playlist!, filter: filter)
        }else {
            self.filteredSongs = SQLiteManager.getSongs(filter: filter)
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText == "" {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    private func initSearchBar() {
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = true
    }


    private func initNavigationBar() {
        searchButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        if (fullListOfSongs()) {
            searchButton.isEnabled = false
            dataManager?.buttons.append(searchButton)
        }
        settingsButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.title = "Songs"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    }


    @IBAction func SearchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        showSearchBar()
    }


    private func showSearchBar(){
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = false
        self.searchController.isActive = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![0].isEnabled = false
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![0].image = nil
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1].isEnabled = false
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1].image = nil
    }

    private func hideSearchBar() {
        navigationItem.titleView?.isHidden = true

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![0].isEnabled = true
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![0].image = UIImage(named: "settings")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1].isEnabled = true
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1].image = UIImage(named: "search")

    }

    func isFiltering() -> Bool {
        if(searchController == nil){
            return false
        }
        return searchController.isActive && !isSearchBarEmpty()
    }

    private func isSearchBarEmpty() -> Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    private func fullListOfSongs() -> Bool {
        return self.playlist == nil && self.albumID == nil && self.artistID == nil
    }

}
```

Comment: how you are trying to open songsController? Means, you are presenting or pushing and on which controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked when I tested. I believe the problem is in `SongsTableViewController`: `self.definesPresentationContext = false`. This should be `true` for the pushed View Controller. (see docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext))

For `SongsTableViewController` (pushed view controller) add the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

And add this to `AlbumsCollectionViewController` (initial view controller):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.definesPresentationContext = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are on `SongsTableViewController`, your `AlbumsCollectionViewController` is not in the window hierarchy.

What I can understand, you are calling `showSearchBar` method of `AlbumsCollectionViewController` from `SongsTableViewController`. And since you navigated from `AlbumsCollectionViewController` to `SongsTableViewController`, your `AlbumsCollectionViewController` is not in the window hierarchy hence wont able to present the search controller.

To fix try adding a separate searchbar controller in `SongsTableViewController` just as you previously did in `AlbumsCollectionViewController`.

Alternatively you can create a seperate viewcontroller, implement search functionality and then present it from both of your controllers.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear. I have a separate `UISearchController` in `SongsTableViewController`. I meant I am using the same logic in both controllers.

Comment: But your error says that you are trying to present search controller from the one which is not currently in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Can you give the code of your SongsTableViewController? How are you presenting the search in that view controller.